# How do I instantiate an object in VB.NET without storing to a variable?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I would like to create an instance of an object and execute a method of the object, but not go through the extra step of storing that instance in a declared variable.

For example, suppose I have a simple Adder class:

```
public class Adder
{
    private int m_int1;
    private int m_int2;
    public Adder(int int1, int int2)
    {
        this.m_int1 = int1;
        this.m_int2 = int2;
    }
    public int getSum()
    {
        return m_int1 + m_int2;
    }
}
```

I can of course create an instance, store in a variable, and use it:

```
Adder a = new Adder(1, 2);
int rslt = a.getSum();
// rslt = 3
```

However, in C#, I can skip the variable storage step, and just call the method on the result of the instantiation:

```
int rslt = new Adder(1, 2).getSum();
// rslt = 3
```

I can't seem to do the same in VB.NET, however. A statement like:

```
New Adder(1, 2)
```

is considered a syntax error unless the result is stored in a variable.

The workaround would be to create a static "Create" method in the class that returns a new instance of the class, but I was wondering if there is a VB.NET equivalent to what's possible in C#.

Comment: Did you try Dim result as Int32 = (New Adder(1, 2)).getSum()? (which is what you were doing in your c# example)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rslt As Integer = New Adder(1, 2).getSum()
```

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I had run into the problem and done some initial tests based on a non-returning object method (sub). I had assumed that because the non-returning case didn't work, the returning case wouldn't either. New MyObject().DoSomethingNoReturn() doesn't work, but Dim rslt = New MyObject().DoSomethingWithReturn() does.